# Negotiating a starting date (one week)

Tags: job-change, start-date

So I got a GREAT offer and they want me to start in the middle of February (14th).
I have a very good relationship with the people I work with currently and they would like me to stay an additional week (till the 20th) to finish up some things. I am inclined to do this as a week is a reasonable time to ask for an extension with 2 months' notice to the new employer.

Since this is my first time switching jobs, how to do I go about speaking to the new employer about a week's extension on the proposed date? I figure I should mail HR prior to signing anything asking for an additional week as it is currently December and this is ample notice for an extension. However, I don't want to jeopardise this new offer under any circumstances. How do I approach this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renegotiating a start date on request of current employer (after contract signed)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/180625/renegotiating-a-start-date-on-request-of-current-employer-after-contract-signed)

Comment: Have you already signed the offer?

Comment: No, offer not signed. It seemed prudent to speak to my current employer first.

Comment: So I have the contract from the new employer. All the specifics are there (salary, benefits etc.). The only thing I want to negotiate is the start date.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> they would like me to stay an additional week (till the 20th) to finish up some things.

Of course, they would like you to, but is it really necessary? You are given them already a really generous notice period of two month. Surely they can hand over you responsibilities to someone else and wrap your current work up on two month!

> How do I approach this?

At this point your highest priority is your new employer. If that's a inconvenience to your current one, it's their problem not your.

You can call your new hiring manager or recruiter and casually ask how strongly they feel about the starting date. If you get the lightest hint of annoyance or hesitation, just let it go and stick with your existing notice period and start date.

Comment: this is the way to go - I think I misread the question a bit ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Since this is my first time switching jobs, how to do I go about
> speaking to the new employer about a week's extension on the proposed
> date? I figure I should mail HR prior to signing anything asking for
> an additional week as it is currently December and this is ample
> notice for an extension. However, I don't want to jeopardise this new
> offer under any circumstances. How do I approach this?

Don't email, just call and ask.

Speak to the hiring manager if at all possible. If that's not possible, speak to HR.

Just explain your situation and ask if an extra week would be possible. Then listen closely. If there's any pushback, or if you sense this is a big burden, then don't insist - just tell your current employer that you can't extend your notice period.

While this is indeed ample notice for an extension, it's also ample notice for your current employer. Your obligation is to your new employer now, they need to come first, if an extension doesn't work out for everyone. You don't want to start a new job on the wrong foot.

Answer (score 0):

#### You ask the new company if it's an issue.

If it is, you start on their preferred date.